# Sorting an arraycollection with a numeric value coming from 2 diffrent fields

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, actionscript-3, sorting

Hi guys I need to sort an arraycollection. the problem is that my array is combined from two diffrent arrays, in one the age field is called "AGE", and in the other the age is called "MYAGE".

Now I need to sort the combined array according to age but I got two fields with diffrent names. I can go through the array and change all "MYAGE" to "AGE" but i was wondering if theres maybe a way to sort the array in its current status?

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an ArrayCollection called `myCollection`. I hope the following will solve your request for that:

```
private function compareItems(a:Object, b:Object, fields:Array = null):int
{
    var firstValue:Number = "AGE" in a ? a["AGE"] : a["MYAGE"];
    var secondValue:Number = "AGE" in b ? b["AGE"] : b["MYAGE"];
    if (firstValue == secondValue)
        return 0;
    return firstValue > secondValue ? 1 : -1;
}

…

var sort:ISort = new Sort();
sort.compareFunction = compareItems;
myCollection.sort = sort;
myCollection.refresh();
```

Comment: If "AGE" in a doesn't work (I have seen documentation state that it only works on dynamic object properties), then you can also test with .hasOwnProperty().  Example:  a.hasOwnProperty("AGE").  http://adobe.ly/oVeR8m